# Closure definition on intuitions

Tags: general-topology

By definition, closure of a subset of a topological space is the set of all the points whose neighborhood contains a point in the subset.On intuitions,is that means the closure of the subset is a set which is a little 'larger' than the subset?

Comment: it doesn't have to be strictly larger. the closure of a closed set is itself. It is true true in general that a set $X$ is a subset of its closure.

Comment: It's certainly not smaller, so I think that is obvious, right? In other words, aren't you saying that $A\subseteq \overline{A}$?

Comment: My question is actually that how larger of the closure. Can the point of closure or the center of neighborhood be outside of the subset?@MPW @Gage

Comment: better: whose **every** neighbourhood contains a point of the subset. A point has lots of neighbourhoods, normally.

Comment: Can the points of closure be outside of the subset?@HennoBrandsma

Comment: @NFDream  Yes, of course.  With $A=(0,1)$ in the real line, $\overline{A}=[0,1]$.  So 0 and 1 are in the closure but are "outside" $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set "above" $A$.  So, out of all closed sets $C$ with $A \subseteq C$, $\overline{A}$ is always within $C$.  As a consequence, if $A$ is already closed it follows that $A = \overline{A}$.

There is a complete duality with interiors:  the interior of $A$ is the largest open set underneath $A$.  Given any set $A$ in a space $X$, the chain
$$
A^\circ \subseteq A \subseteq \overline{A}
$$
has $A^\circ$ as the best open set approximation to $A$, while $\overline{A}$ is the best closed set approximation to $A$.